# Iterative algorithm for obtaining similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_M$ be $M$ non-negative variables. Moreover, assume that $f_m(x_m)=\frac{x_m}{1+\sum_{n}\beta_{n}^{(m)}x_n}$ be $M$ fractional functions with non-negative constants $\beta_{n}^{(m)}$. Suppose that the vector of variables $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$ additionally satisfy the linear constraint $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\leq\mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $N\times M$ matrix with positive elements. Assume that the initial values $x_1^{(0)},x_2^{(0)},\ldots,x_M^{(0)}$ satisfying all constraints are given. Is there any iterative algorithm such that updates $x_1^{(t)},x_2^{(t)},\ldots,x_M^{(t)}$ in a way that the $f_m(x_m)$'s values be as identical as possible by increasing $t$?

Comment: Well, once you can specify what "as identical as possible" means, you could use this term as objective and minimize this under the constraint… Or do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, you are right. For example max-min is a good choise. But. I want to know if there is any iterative way?